# How to create a customer attribute with options on the fly

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I want to create a custom customer attribute where for example he can complete custom values for

- Complete your 5 best movies

Multiselect does not work because they need a source. There is something that I can create to save that custom data for example in a JSON or so?

Answer (score 1):

hi @martin to create custom customer attribute you have write Installdata.php within MyCompany/MyModule/Setup

```
<?php

 namespace MyCompany\MyNewAttribute\Setup;

 use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 use MyCompany\MyNewAttribute\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\MyNewAttribute;
 use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
 use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;

 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
/**
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
protected $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var EavConfig
 */
private $eavConfig;

/**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
private $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    EavConfig $eavConfig,
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

/**
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Customer::ENTITY,
        'my_new_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'My New Attribue',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'option' => ['values' => [
                           'Option 1',
                           'Option 2',
                           'Option 3',
                           ],
                        ],
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0
        ]
    );

    $usedInForms = [
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'customer_account_create'
    ];

    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_new_attribute');
    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
    $attribute->save();
}}
```

Then run setup:upgrade command and check attribute in customer form.

Please accept & Vote answer if it is helpful. Thanks

Comment: No, i know how to create a custom attribute but i asked for an specific one where you can have options on the fly in a form. Maybe a json custom attribute or something like that were you can store dinamic things no preset options